# How to create or view sql files on Eclipse 2018-12

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-2018-12

I have recently installed **Eclipse IDE 2018-12** IDE.

As part of project, I require to work with `sql(s).`

I don't see sql wizard on opening create file (that was available on earlier Eclipse version Kepler, ...)

When I copy any file to target project, and try to view sql file, it just shows *light blue screen.*

Is there any explicit option that need to activate within IDE or require to download any plugin for sql support?

Comment: What *DBMS/ SQL Dialect are you trying to use?

Comment: 2018-12 is a *version*, it can contain different combinations of features. Did you install the Data Tools?

Comment: @nitind No I haven't installed any tools yet. 
I don't remember did we use to do it for any earlier versions of Eclipse esp. for sql files? Could you please tell me how to install it to fulfill this purpose?

Comment: @DDS I use Oracle Database

Comment: @inityk It depends on which of the packages you downloaded or installed: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare . What were the names of the old and new downloads?

Comment: @nitindI downloaded the standard 64bit IDE. 
Didn't follow your que (What were the names of the old and new downloads)? Could you elaborate? how to check that?
FYI: New download: 2018-12, Older one: Kepler
(Not sure if this was your que)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to install **SQL Development Tools** or **SQL Editor** from Eclipse Marketplace.